# Basics: Can't reference static member in XAML

Tags: wpf

I try to access a static member in XAML but the compiler keeps complaining. Can anyone help.

This is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tt_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tt_WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Button  Content="{x:Static local:MainWindow.SomeString}" />
</Window>
```

This is the code behind

```
namespace tt_WPF
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static string SomeString = "Hello";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would help to post the error your receiving. I've still posted an answer though, your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine as-is, with no changes.

[image: Window with a Button that says "Hello"]

If it won't let you compile, I'd recommend doing a Clean Solution and restarting Visual Studio. If that doesn't work, try creating a new WPF project and copying your code in, incase some other file is messed up.

Comment: Thanks. Never suspected Visual Studio!